# How to solve "NameError: name 'df' is not defined" problem

Tags: python

```
#Importing dependencies
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from tld import get_tld
import os.path
import pandas as pd

#First Directory Length
def fd_length(url):
    urlpath= urlparse(url).path
    try:
        return len(urlpath.split('/')[1])
    except:
        return 0

df['fd_length'] = df['url'].apply(lambda i: fd_length(i))
```

Error

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_12736\2713442429.py in <module>
     13         return 0
     14 
---> 15 df['fd_length'] = df['url'].apply(lambda i: fd_length(i))

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

How to solve that problem?

Comment: You never assigned a dataframe to `df`.

Comment: I am a beginner.Please give me the solution code

Comment: That is not how it works. The comment clearly points you towards the error (as the error message itself already did). Now it is your time doe research again. Hint you need code beginning with `df = [...]`, as you imported pandas I guess it will be something like `df = pd.readcsv([...])`

Comment: df=pd.read_csv('malicious_phish.csv')
print(df.shape)
df.head()
I use it 
but try,catch is not work with lambda function and show df is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code is that variable named `df` is not defined. If you want to use a csv file and import it as pandas dataframe, you can use pandas `read_csv` method which you can learn more about in [pandas documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

```
# I want to read "name.csv" file
df = pd.read_csv("name.csv")
# It should be present in the same path as the python file
# It will work with url also.
```

Comment: from urllib.parse import urlparse
from tld import get_tld
import os.path
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('malicious_phish.csv')
print(df.shape)
df.head()
#First Directory Length
def fd_length(url):
    urlpath= urlparse(url).path
    try:
        return len(urlpath.split('/')[1])
    except:
        return 0

df['fd_length'] = df['url'].apply(lambda i: fd_length(i))
#Try and catch cannot work with lambda function,how to fix it

Comment: `def fd_length(url):
    try:
        urlpath= urlparse(url).path
        return len(urlpath.split('/')[1])
    except:
        return 0`
Try it like this, it should work.

Comment: Sir,same error is showing,

Comment: @Md.MahbubMurshid - If you have a different script, post that in the original question. Its hard to read as a comment.